# Having trouble using psexec to update user credentials on remote computer

Tags: remote, psexec

I maintain a computer lab. I don't want to reimage these computers just yet, but I do want to update the user credentials for the lab without having to go around to each and every computer and doing it manually.

I have installed psexec on my technician computer and have been trying to change the credentials on the remote computer by running the following commands:

```
psexec \\\remotecomputername net user testuser password /add
```

The problem I get is that it tells me "The account already exists" when it doesn't.

Just as a test, I restarted the target computer and ran psexec again. I get a return code of 0, no errors, I assume it worked. But I tried the credentials on the remote computer and it is still accepting the old credentials, not the new.

I tried this on another computer as well after removing the user account completely and running the command again and that didn't work either.

Can't seem to figure out what I'm missing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a -s to your command before the computer name. 
EX:
psexec -s \remotecomputername net user testuser password /add

-s runs the command as system which i usually have luck with